# Transactionally change records in collection

Tags: java, collections, transactional

I have this code:

```
import java.util.*;


class MyClass {
    public Boolean field;
}


public class Main {

    Map<String, MyClass> map = new HashMap<>();

    private void fillCollection() {

        MyClass record1 = new MyClass();
        MyClass record2 = new MyClass();
        MyClass record3 = new MyClass();

        record1.field = false;
        record2.field = false;
        record3.field = false;

        map.put("record1", record1);
        map.put("record2", record2);
        map.put("record3", record3);
    }

    private void changeObject(MyClass record) throws Exception {

        if (new Random().nextInt(2) == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Exception during Object change");
        }

        record.field = true;
    }

    private void changeCollection(List<String> recordKeys) {

        for (String key : recordKeys) {
            try {
                changeObject(map.get(key));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void printCollection() {

        for (String key : map.keySet()) {

            System.out.println(key + " " + map.get(key).field);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Main application = new Main();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                application.fillCollection();
            }
        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(100);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                List<String> recordKeys = new ArrayList<>();
                recordKeys.add("record1");
                recordKeys.add("record2");

                application.changeCollection(recordKeys);
            }
        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(100);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                application.printCollection();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Еxplanation:

- There is the Map of Objects (keys are Strings).
- In one thread this Map is filled with Objects.
- In other thread some (not all) Objects should be changed. During the change of the Object some Exception can be thrown (in case above it is simulated in method "changeObject"). In case of Exception Object shouldn't be added to Map.

This is the thing: addition of all Objects in Map should be transactional. Maybe I not use the rigth word here, so I explain: in the end either all records should be changed or none of them should be changed.

So the question is: Can it be achieved? How should "changeCollection" method looks like?

Currently I use the following solution: I create temporary map, fill it with clones of records from main map, try to change clone records in this temporary map, and in case of absence of exceptions I make main map variable to point to temporary map object. I don't like this solution and prefer the solution without clones if it exists.

Another thing: I don't want to you any external libraries.

Comment: Standard collections are not transactional. Therefore I believe that your current approach is your best choice. Perhaps you could use a putAll instead of changing the "pointer".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved. Please take a look at the below snippet.

```
public class MapWrapper {

    // this needs to be volatile
    private volatile Map<String, MyClass> map;

    // this needs to be synchronized 
    public synchronized fillMap() {
        // you have single access to the map, fill it as needed
    }

    // this needs to be synchronized 
    public synchronized editMap() {
        // you have single access to the map
        Map<String, MyClass> clone = deepCloneMap(map); 
        try {
           // modify the clone map
           // as the last instruction in the try block, reassign references 
           map = clone; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // deal with exception, don't reassign the reference to roll back  
        }
    }

}
```